# How does "Disable cache" work?

Tags: cache, cloudflare, cdn, google-chrome

I have a website managed by CloudFlare and its CDN.

when we choose `Disable cache` in Dev Tools of Google Chrome like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7000899/8111022), by definition the browser refreshes static files.

However, I would like to know whether the browser refreshes static files from **my server** or from the **CDN**?

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously from the CDN. Unless you tell CLoudflare to bypass it's cache, cloudflare will use the locally cached copies as per it's rules. Browser Dev Tools do not magically change that.